# Wrong column order from query SQL Server - no-one can answer this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2014. I have to produce a data extract as text file for our client and it must have a trailer row at the bottom of the extract

So at the bottom of the table in Row A it needs to have 'TRL' and at the bottom of the table in Row B it needs to have the count of rows containing data minus the header row

When I run the query in SQL it returns in the order I want. But when I set up a data connection to Excel it comes out in a different order

The below is a simple mock-up of how I need the extract to appear for the client

[image]

Below now is the query in SQL server that I am using

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DateOfCall AS sql_variant) AS 'DateOfCall', 
    CAST(AgentName AS sql_variant) AS 'AgentName', 
    Connects, Completes, DMC, COMPANY_BPID, 
    ContactNumber, TalkTime, Disposition, Campaign, CA, 
    mpan_mpr, Installer, PKCallResults
FROM 
    dbo.CompanyX_CallResults C
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CompanyX_ContactInfo X ON C.CallAccount = X.PKCustomerRecord
WHERE 
    DateOfCall BETWEEN '2020-10-15 00:00:01' AND '2020-10-15 23:59:59'
    AND PoolFK = 504

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'TRL ' AS Detail,
    COUNT(AgentName) - 1 AS ROWID,
    '' AS Detail3, '' AS Detail4,
    '' AS Detail5, '' AS Detail6,
    '' AS Detail7, '' AS Detail8,
    '' AS Detail9, '' AS Detail10,
    '' AS Detail11, '' AS Detail12,
    '' AS Detail13, '' AS Detail14
FROM 
    dbo.CompanyX_CallResults
```

The query works fine but when I set up a connection to Excel the order of the columns come out wrong!

`DateOfCall` and `AgentName` which should be Column A and Column B are then Column D and E

And I can't figure it out and neither can my other colleagues

Please any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It shouldn't affect the outcome but you don't need column names in the second half of your `union` - they are ignored.

Comment: Which columns *do* show up as column A and B?

Answer (score 0):

In a common table expresssion `CTE` you could assign an 'Order_Hierarchy' column where the "date of call details" are assigned the value of 1 and the summary row is assigned 2.  Then select from the `CTE` and include the clause: `ORDER BY` Order_Hierarchy.  Also, per @AlwaysLearning, the column names in the second half of the UNION ALL aren't necessary but I left them in.  Something like this

```
with union_cte as (
    SELECT 
        1 as Order_Hierarchy,
        CAST(DateOfCall AS sql_variant) AS DateOfCall, 
        CAST(AgentName AS sql_variant) AS AgentName, 
        Connects, Completes, DMC, COMPANY_BPID, 
        ContactNumber, TalkTime, Disposition, Campaign, CA, 
        mpan_mpr, Installer, PKCallResults
    FROM 
        dbo.CompanyX_CallResults C
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.CompanyX_ContactInfo X ON C.CallAccount = X.PKCustomerRecord
    WHERE 
        DateOfCall BETWEEN '2020-10-15 00:00:01' AND '2020-10-15 23:59:59'
        AND PoolFK = 504
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        2 as Order_Hierarchy,
        'TRL ' AS Detail,
        COUNT(AgentName) - 1 AS ROWID,
        '' AS Detail3, '' AS Detail4,
        '' AS Detail5, '' AS Detail6,
        '' AS Detail7, '' AS Detail8,
        '' AS Detail9, '' AS Detail10,
        '' AS Detail11, '' AS Detail12,
        '' AS Detail13, '' AS Detail14
    FROM 
        dbo.CompanyX_CallResults)
select DateOfCall, AgentName,  Connects, Completes, DMC, COMPANY_BPID, 
        ContactNumber, TalkTime, Disposition, Campaign, CA, 
        mpan_mpr, Installer, PKCallResults
from union_cte
order by Order_Hierarchy;
```

Comment: But this is completely unrelated to "order of COLUMNS". And your sort logic is almost as flawed as OP's - you correctly force the trailer row to always be last but the data rows have no defined order.

Comment: @SMor you've made assumptions based on the apparent ordering.  The original query did not contain an Order By clause, therefore, those assumptions are questionable.  If the OP would like the output of the query to match the apparent ordering then the ORDER BY would be by Order_Hierarchy, AgentName, DateOfCall.